# Reduce font size in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs

I created a document with Google Docs. Now I want to reduce the fontsize by 1pt. There are several fontsizes in the documents, so I can't just apply a different size to the whole document.

In MS Word, you can select all and press Ctrl+Shift+.

Is this possible in Google Docs?

Comment: Not Ctr+Shift++ but Ctrl+Shift+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this possible in Google Docs?

Yes, it is.

#### With keyboard shortcuts

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (that's the <kbd>comma</kbd> key)

#### With menu commands

1. Menu `Edit` → `Select all`
   [image: Google Docs Select all menu]
2. Menu `Format` → `Font size` → `Decrease font size`
   [image: Google Docs Decrease font size menu]

Answer (score 6):

No it's not possible in the current version of the Google Docs, but they are adding more things every now and then. You can find all the shortcuts keys that are used in docs [here](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179738).

Comment: Works now, as described in comment by @Lernkurve

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**Numeric Key Pad** and further more try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**Numeric Key Pad** and then see what happens. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**Numeric Key Pad** & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
Try different Keys and see the magic. You'll learn a lot. Or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on your current document and see what happens.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Still no increasing font size though. Ctrl+Alt+NumericKeyPad changes the current paragraph to a header.

Comment: Works now, as described in comment by @Lernkurve

Answer (score 1):

This works...
copy and paste from Google to Microsoft Word.

Within MS Word, decrease or increase font size as desired with <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>[</kbd>

Then copy and paste back to Google Docs.

Comment: Ha. Nice find :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a hack but to go less than font 6 you can make them superscript (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>) or subscript (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Long-winded and well meaning thread, but I have often searched for exactly the same thing, i.e. a keyboard shortcut for Google Docs to increase/decrease font size for selected text incrementally.

Unfortunately, there is no such keyboard shortcut implemented at this time. A total mystery to me—it would strike me as being one of the most commonly used keyboard shortcuts. Perhaps there is some funky reason to do with browsers or something. Come on Google, make it happen please!

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix:

- Set up Heading/style no. 6 and use it's keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. You don't even need to select the text, just place the cursor in the text-segment.

Sometimes you might need to "activate" the shortcut, by using the documents Heading/style function (with your mouse) once.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question

Comment: I assumed you didn't just want to change the size of all "normal" text and that you could make do with having a keyboard shortcut to quickly change certain sections to ONE predefined size. Is that correct?

Comment: I can add the first part as an answer if that will answer your question?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the shortcut Ctrl+A to select all & decrease the font size from the dropdown in the toolbar

Comment: I can select a specific font size, but that is not what I want, because it would give all text the same font size. Or am I overlooking some option?

Answer (score -2):

Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> to reduce or increase font size.

Comment: This does nothing for me if I try it correctly (i.e. holding the shift modifier). However, since "<" and ">" are the same key for "," and "." (depending on keyboard), you may be seeing the effect of changing the selected text to subscript or superscript which are linked to the "Ctrl + ," and "Ctrl + ." . That would seem to reduce the effective size of the text, but would disallow using sub/super script in that part of the text.

Answer (score -2):

Click the "select all" cell at top left of your Google doc. It'll highlight everything; then select the font and font size you want.

Comment: This is the same answer as that of mvark, see comment there.